# Is os.FileInfo actively querying the filesystem, or is it the result of such a query?

Tags: go

Concretely: if I os.Stat a file and save the result in a variable I call "stat", then the file is appended to, then I do "stat.Size()", will it be the old size or the new size? Is this behavior guaranteed cross platform? It appears to be the former on Linux.

Comment: None of the FileInfo methods return errors, meaning they cannot fail. That's only feasible if the information is cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the source:

os/types_unix.go:
This defines fileStat as a static structure, so for unix, stat performs the query and fileStat is static.

os/types_windows.go:
The fileStat for windows is much more involved. However, Size(), ModTime(), and Mode() are functions that return fixed values without making any other system calls.

So at least for these two systems, Stat() constructs an os-specific structure that is a snapshot of the values at the time Stat() was called.